# Double Integral Circle not centered at Origin

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, geometry, definite-integrals

For a circle centered at $(2,0)$ with radius $1$, calculate $\int\int x dA$. I know this will give $r^2 cos\theta dr d\theta$ inside the integral. For the limits of $\theta$, I have $+-$$\frac{\pi}{2}$. I am confused for $r$.

Equation of circle is $(x-2)^2 + y^2 = 1$. I convert to polar coordinates and get $r^2-4rcos\theta + 3$, but I don't know what to do from there. Should I solve this using the quadratic formula?

Comment: do you want to find the area of the circle or do you want to find it by solving the integral specifically

Comment: By solving the integral. I know the answer is $2 \pi$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are integrating over the area delimited by a circumference centered at (2,0) and, accordingly, you have

$x-2 = r \cos\theta$

$y = r\sin\theta$

Then, with $x = 2+r \cos\theta$, and $dA = r\,dr\,d\theta$,

\begin{align}
I = \int\int x \, dA = 2\int_{0}^{1} dr\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} d\theta \;
 (2+r\cos\theta) r = 2\pi + \frac{4}{3}
\end{align}

The same answer can be obtained in Cartesian coordinates as

\begin{align}
I = \int\int x\, dA = 4\int_{2}^{3} x\, dx\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-(x-2)^2}} dy = 4\int_{2}^{3} x \sqrt{1-(x-2)^2}\, dx = 2\pi + \frac{4}{3}
\end{align}